# Remove part of a text string

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  
   right(name,7),
   substring(params, charindex('|-|', params)+3,LEN(params)) as 'List Name', 
   convert(varchar,dateadd(hh,-8,created_date), 101) as Date, 
   convert(char, dateadd(hh,-8,created_date), 108) as Time 
FROM 
   [meldb].[dbo].[mr_message]
WHERE
   name in ('CL_LIST_STARTED', 'CL_LIST_STOPPED')
   AND dateadd(hh,-8,created_date) > '7/1/2014'
ORDER BY 
   created_date ASC
```

List name will return something like:

```
firstname.lastname-|LISTNAME|-|PARENTLISTNAME
```

I'm trying to isolate `LISTNAME` and `PARENTLISTNAME` into separate columns, but since they can vary in char size I can't just specify right or left

Btw I didn't create this table I'm just stuck using it

Any ideas?

Comment: sql server, sorry forgot to specify

Comment: Can you show some example rows? Is the format how you have it with . separating firstname last name and - separating listname and parentlist name.

Comment: seprators are |-|  but there are two instances of "|-|"

so far im here:

Comment: SELECT right(name,7),
  substring(params, charindex('|-|', params)+3,LEN(params)) as 'List Name', 
  convert(varchar,dateadd(hh,-8,created_date), 101) as Date, 
  convert(char, dateadd(hh,-8,created_date), 108) as Time 
 
 FROM [meldb].[dbo].[mr_message]
  where name in ('CL_LIST_STARTED', 'CL_LIST_STOPPED')
  and dateadd(hh,-8,created_date) > '7/1/2014'
  order by created_date asc

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you really want to do this in t-sql, I think you're on track with CHARINDEX.  You'll have to do a loop where you store the last value from CHARINDEX as the start-location for the next call.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Oh, you want this for multiple rows like a single select?   Hmmmm... maybe need a UDF then.

Comment: Also, can you indicate the SQL Server version?

Comment: Cool...   Oh, and I just realized you're saying it's exactly 2 delimiters, not a variable number of delimiters, right?  Then we can hardcode the nesting with CHARINDEX...  go for it!  I'll race you :)

Comment: Do you want to separate `params` into three columns?

Comment: @Jesuraja in a weird way yes, i dont care for the firstname.lastname, so realistically it would be sep into two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it yet?
Ok...   happy friday :)

```
declare @str varchar(100);
set @str = 'jim.smith|-|firstItem|-|secondItem';



--- for your query, change @str to the column name, obviously ---
select 
    substring(
                    @str
                    , charindex('|-|', @str) + 3
                    , ( ( charindex('|-|', @str, charindex('|-|', @str) + 3) ) - ( charindex('|-|', @str) + 3) )
                )
    ,substring(
                    @str
                    , charindex('|-|', @str, charindex('|-|', @str) + 3) + 3
                    , len(@str) -- guaranteed to be past the end, to catch all
                )
```

Comment: oh, it's in there :)  I like more lines than most people ...  have a good weekend

Comment: worked Mike! thanks, I wasnt including the second charindex and it was driving me nuts! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to split `params` into three columns? Please check below query.

```
SELECT  
   SUBSTRING(params, 1, CHARINDEX('-', params)-1) AS FullName,
   SUBSTRING(STUFF(params, CHARINDEX('|-|', params), LEN(params), ''), CHARINDEX('-', params) + 2, LEN(params)) AS 'List Name', 
   SUBSTRING(params, CHARINDEX('|-|', params) + 3, LEN(params)) AS 'Parent List Name', 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(hh,-8,created_date), 101) AS DATE, 
   CONVERT(CHAR, DATEADD(hh,-8,created_date), 108) AS TIME 
FROM 
   [meldb].[dbo].[mr_message]
WHERE
   name IN ('CL_LIST_STARTED', 'CL_LIST_STOPPED')
   AND DATEADD(hh,-8,created_date) > '7/1/2014'
ORDER BY 
   created_date ASC
```

Comment: close but that retruned the following three colums:
fulle name - first.last
list name  - LISTNAME|-|PARENTLISTNAME(partial)
Parent list name - LISTNAME|-|PARENTLISTNAME(complete)

Comment: Can you update exact Sample input and Expected Output in your question?

Comment: well it retruned more but i was referencing the 3 substring colums

Comment: Update please check now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the format I came up with using PAT index and the separators you mentioned:

```
SELECT name,
substring(name, 0, charindex('.', name)) as 'FirstName',
substring(name, charindex('.', name) + 1, patindex('%|-|%', name) - patindex('%-|%', name) -2) as 'LastName',
substring(name,patindex('%-|%', name)+2, patindex('%|-|%', name) - patindex('%-|%', name)-2) as 'ListName',
substring(name, patindex('%|-|%', name)+3, len(name) - patindex('%|-|%', name)) as 'ParentListName'
from FancyNames
```

Link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03c2c/38